# Can you create multiple tables with one query in Google Big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

[New create table feature has been released](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language) and I was wondering if it's possible to create 2 or more tables with one query.

I tried, but it returns error

> Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword CREATE at [8:1]

```
 #standardSQL
 CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE newtables_test.cg1_uk
 OPTIONS(
   description="blah blah blah"
 ) AS 
select 'x' as y;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE newtables_test.cg1_uk2 
as
select 'y' as x
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: what is use case for this? can you share please

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I have query where I need final output of it, but also some mid steps to use them for other queries, but since I'm forced to use app scripts to schedule jobs, I'm not sure exactly when tables are ready and I want to avoid number of triggers I need to get something + also have data as soon as possible. So let's say query A produces table t1, t2 and final result t3 between 7 and 8 AM and I can use all 3 tables in queries B, C and D scheduled for 8-9AM. otherwise I need to process the same data 4 times for each table. Is it clear enough? Because I feel it's not....

Comment: I can be wrong - but I don't think creating of multiple tables in one shot  (even if it supported) would help you in this case

Comment: It would. Probably I haven't described it accurately enough, but I could do everything in 2 timeslots instead of 3 or 4 slots so reporting would be ready before 10, not before 12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the documentation link in your question:

> Only one CREATE statement is allowed.

So, looks like you cannot. Maybe someone else has a trick/workaround, but I'm not aware of any.

Comment: Multistatement query support is often mentioned as a feature request - so it would be useful to know your usage scenario to inform feature design.

Answer (score 3):

2 years later, still can't run multiple CREATE TABLE in one statement. The docs still list  "CREATE TABLE statements must comply with the following rules: Only one CREATE statement is allowed." https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language

But there is a solution. Separate the CREATE TABLE statements by using a terminating semicolon ( ; ). Example:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_a AS SELECT id, c1, c2, c3 FROM t1;
CREATE TABLE new_table_b AS SELECT id, c4, c5, c6 FROM t1;
SELECT [...]
```

Comment: right on!!!!!!!